# My Node Script Hangs after functions are finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm calling three functions, after the completion of these functions I want my script to close on it's own but it just hangs.

I've tried making the functions async/promise based, closing the database after each 'mongodb' type function, and using process.exit() within a function as a callback to the last called function.

Connecting to the (local - not Atlas) Database:

```
MongoClient.connect(local, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  else {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB...')
    //Read in data from jsonfiles and store each file's contents into the database : This is where the functions are being called... within a successful connect to the MongoDB
    insertJSON(db, jsonfiles, 'requests', jsonfilesSource)
    insertJSON(db, issuedfiles, 'issuedLicenses', isssuedfilesSource)
    insertLicenses(db)
  }
  db.close()
})
```

Function 1:

```
function insertJSON(db, dirBuf,collection, sourceFolder) {
  var database = db.db('license-server')
  var collection = database.collection(collection)
  fs.readdir(dirBuf, function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.message)
    }
    else {
      files.forEach(function(filename) {
        var text = fs.readFileSync(sourceFolder + filename);
        var filecontents = JSON.parse(text)
        //collection.insertOne(filecontents)
        collection.findOne({"DisplayTitle" : filecontents.DisplayTitle, "NodeInformation" : filecontents.NodeInformation, "Date": filecontents.Date})
          .then(function(result) {
            if(result) {
              console.log(`An Item could already be in the database: A file is unique if its display title, nodeinformation, and date are different.
              the items display title is ${result.DisplayTitle}`)
              return
            }
            else {
              collection.insertOne(filecontents)
              console.log(`Added ${filecontents.DisplayTitle} to database`)
            }
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
          })
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Function 2:

```
function insertLicenses(db) {
  // Set up GridFS to import .lic and .licx files into the database
  var database = db.db('license-server')
  var collection = database.collection('fs.files')
  var bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(database);
  var dirBuf = Buffer.from('../license-server/private/licenses')
  fs.readdir(dirBuf, function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.message)
    }
    else {
      files.forEach(function(filename) {
        collection.findOne({"filename": filename}).
        then(function(result) {
          if(result) {
            console.log(`The file ${filename} is already in the database`)
            return
          }
          else {
            fs.createReadStream('./private/licenses/' + filename).
            pipe(bucket.openUploadStream(filename)).
            on('error', function(error) {
              assert.ifError(error)
            }).
            on('finish', function() {
              console.log(`Uploaded ${filename}`)
            })
          }
        })
      })
    }
  })
// I tried calling db.close() here since this is the last function to be called. No luck.
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the mongodb functions having their own way to close themselves but I couldn't seem to find what I was looking for in previous attempts to resolve this issue.

The expected result should be the script closing itself, the actual result is a handing script.

Answer (score 2):

All of these database calls are asynchronous -- the result of this code running is to immediately call `db.close` and then do the work in `insertJSON` and `insertLicenses`. If you were to rewrite this to use `async/await` (and you'd need to update your other functions as well) the `db.close` call would close the db, and that would allow the script to exit:

```
  await insertJSON(db, jsonfiles, 'requests', jsonfilesSource)
  await insertJSON(db, issuedfiles, 'issuedLicenses', isssuedfilesSource)
  await insertLicenses(db)
  db.close()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function